# Uploading large files in laravel 8

Tags: file-upload, laravel-8

I would like to upload a large file, not more than 300mb on size. I will upload the file into the database. I have added the upload button in my form. My issue is how can I make this possible considering there is a limit to upload files. I have successfully uploaded other files which are less than 2mb and it have successfully uploaded.kindly help o how to go about on this, I am using laravel 8

Comment: Increase your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184541/3965631. Also, don't store files in your database. Upload to a server (local filesystem or something like AWS S3), and store the file location/reference in the database.

Comment: Note that the upload time increases with larger files. This can cause timeouts for users with low bandwidth. You may have to adjust the `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` and the timeout of the web server. If you have no influence on these parameters, the upload may be split up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using **xampp | windows 10 | Laravel 8**

There are several methods to achieve this, you can pick as per your requirement.

1. Xampp Apache Configuration : **XXX:\xampp\php\php.ini**

   [image: Xampp Configuration]
2. Updating in **.htaccess** file :-

   ```
    <IfModule php7_module>
       php_flag display_errors On
       php_value max_execution_time 999
       php_value max_input_time 999
       php_value max_input_vars 1000
       php_value memory_limit 9999M
       php_value post_max_size 9999M
       php_value upload_max_filesize 9999M
    </IfModule>
   ```
3. Creating **php.ini** in public folder so that we can override main configuration of php.

   ```
    display_errors = On
    max_execution_time = 999
    max_input_time = 999
    max_input_vars = 1000
    memory_limit = 9999M
    post_max_size = 9999M
    session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
    upload_max_filesize = 9999M
    zlib.output_compression = Off
   ```

After making changes make sure you always restart your server to see the effect of changes, Plus you can always view the changes by running

```
dd(phpinfo()); OR <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```